# Enable Macros in Excel without Updating External File Links

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have excel documents that have links to extenal files in cells to grab data. These files also have macros. I need to move these excel documents between computers that do and don't have the external files on them  and have the macros enabled in all contexts. For Computers running windows 10 and Excel 2016 without the external files clicking the "Enable Content" button will cause excel to hang for about 10 minutes before a "Can't update links" dialog pops up.

[image: Can't update links" dialog]

How can I enable my macros without causing excel to try and update my links automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the orginal poster and I found a solution that worked for me.

I was able to handle this by using another spreadsheet that opens the problem file using VBA.

Code:

```
Public file As String

Sub Open_File()
    file = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=file, UpdateLinks:=0
End Sub
```

Spreadsheet:

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet For Above Code]

The Open File button is linked to the Open_File() function in VBA. It will open a file in the same folder as this file with a name set in Cell D4. The opened file won't update links and its marcos will be enabled.